# How can I encrypt and decrypt a string in php?

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

According to this tutorial https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/two-way-encryption/ I try to encrypt and decrypt a string.

The encryption works well:

```
  $token = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

  $cipher_method = 'aes-128-ctr';
  $enc_key = openssl_digest(php_uname(), 'SHA256', TRUE);
  $enc_iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher_method));
  $crypted_token = openssl_encrypt($token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, 0, $enc_iv) . "::" . bin2hex($enc_iv);
  unset($token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $enc_iv);

  var_dump($crypted_token);
```

The output is `KZ4LurHESC0Y8/Ufy1wsio6aaYXW7m7KVuW8NBKQhE5CnLspz+540p1ClhIZvKNx::254f830c42c937fb7e1e2444c632a8a4`

But when I want to decrypt it again:

```
$crypted_token = "KZ4LurHESC0Y8/Ufy1wsio6aaYXW7m7KVuW8NBKQhE5CnLspz+540p1ClhIZvKNx::254f830c42c937fb7e1e2444c632a8a4";

  list($crypted_token, $enc_iv) = explode("::", $crypted_token);;
  $cipher_method = 'aes-128-ctr';
  $enc_key = openssl_digest(php_uname(), 'SHA256', TRUE);
  $token = openssl_decrypt($crypted_token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, 0, hex2bin($enc_iv));
  unset($crypted_token, $cipher_method, $enc_key, $enc_iv);

  var_dump($token);
```

I get the output:

```
"m PHĝ��Jt�nx���l����$�۩!Z��� [b���f�"
```

As I am expecting:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in code. php_uname() disabled. enable php_uname() and try again.

Comment: I tried with your crypted token but my output is `��b�Ì�U��Q@�bƃ�-G6������!�m�,+�m�`

Comment: @peace_love use same code i have put in answer and see that is working on my end

Comment: I copied your code to a php tester and sent you a screenshot

Comment: @peace_love it is coming because php_uname() is disabled. please enable and try again.

see warning : php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: How do I do this? On my mac oder in the console.? in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the response is in binary format. Try to convert it using hex2bin() and see what you get.